# How do I make an EditText have a certain maximum width, but not go off the screen?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-edittext

I'm trying to set up an EditText that has a set width, but if the screen is smaller than this width, does not extend off the screen. I've tried a number of variations of layout_width and maxWidth and the like, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can set the size of the `EditText` dynamically (from code) based on the screen size. If you want to know how to get the screen width, let me know.

Comment: How about a relative layout anchoring the EditText to the parent edge ?  What do you expect to happen if the screen is too small?

Comment: So basically you want to have a line break every time the EditText is too long? Did I ubderstand it right?